# Google PubSub: do not receive old messages

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

We are using Google PubSub for an IoT project in a multi-tenant system

- Each device from the same tenant delivers a 'heartbeat' message every
  minute.
- Each tenant has its own topic.
- Each device has its own subscription to the topic.

The problem we are having is:  when we un-plug a device for a couple of days, and then re-plug it, it starts to receive hundreds of messages (old heartbeats from the other devices) that make the device slow for a few minutes.

The question is:

**What do you think is the correct way to work with this?**

- one topic per device?
- is there a way to clear the suscription and avoid receiving old messages?

We are open to recommendations.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Cloud Pub/Sub, messages will be retained for subscriptions for 7 days. Therefore, if your device reconnects, it will receive up to 7 days worth of messages.

To skip older messages, one can use [seek](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/seek) on a Pub/Sub subscription (currently in alpha) to ack older messages by seeking to a timestamp corresponding to now. The devices could each call this API when they start up before they start to subscribe as a means to clear out the older messages.

Regarding your setup in general, how many tenants and devices do you have? Keep in mind the [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas): a single project can only have 10,000 topics and 10,000 subscriptions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  We'll check on the Monitoring API. We are a startup, we use one main topic for device->server messages. (that is the same topic for all devices from all tenants) and one topic per tenant to do the server->(all same tenant devices) messages.
Each device has it own subscription.

Comment: That is what we came up while we designed the sync process. It works well except for the problem in this question. We use GAE on PHP, PubSub is the best solution from all the others we've tried so far!

Comment: if I remove a topic and then create it again with the same name, the messages will get deleted?

Comment: You need to delete the subscription itself. We allow messages to be pulled from a deleted topic. If you delete the subscription, all of the messages for it will be deleted and will not be delivered when you create a new subscription with the same name.

Comment: Has Google made any headway on adding the feature to skip older messages?

Comment: @ChrisDelGuercio Yes, in fact there is an API now available to do this. I have updated the answer with some information about it.